# enable x authentication over ssh for the root

Tags: ssh, xorg

over ssh -

```
$xclock
$sudo su -

#xclock
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
```

so I do -

```
$xauth list /*copy the lines*/ 
$sudo su -
#xauth add /*paste the lines*/
#xclock /* works */
```

I am fed up doing this on every login, how can I persist it?

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't run X11 software as root. Seriously.
2. Use `sudo -s` or `sudo -i` instead of `sudo su`.
3. Add `XAUTHORITY` to sudo's `env_keep` configuration option. It should point to an Xauthority file in your home directory.

Comment: sudo -s was what helped me. Thanks +1.

Comment: Can you provide a pointer why X11 shouldn't be run as root?